# Error al descargar un proyecto desde git

Tags: java, eclipse

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando descargo un proyecto de java desde un repositorio y lo abro en el IDE de eclipse me salen errores en todas partes incluso con el System.out.prinln() no se que clase de instrucción el IDE debo poner para que esto se normalice y me tome los paquetes

https://github.com/anncode1/JavaSEBasicoAvanzado/tree/32.AbstractClases/AmazonViewer

Comment: Puede que hayas escrito por error `rec` al inicio del archivo, esto invalida todo lo que viene. Intenta remover las letras para que solo diga `package` y prueba denuevo.

Comment: es que el codigo no lo escribí yo.. y viendo el curso de donde tome el proyecto no noto ninguna diferencia

Comment: Puede que el proyecto este usando algunas librerias que no tienes, eso o que el propio ide te genere ese error. A mi me pasaba cuando cambiaba de netbeans a eclipse (y viceversa). Ya probaste abriendo el proyecto con otro IDE?

Answer (score 1):

Aparte del problema del codigo que tiene algunos caracteres agregados (`rec`) al inicio. El principal problema es que al importar el projecto este viene configurado con un archivo `.classpath` que indica que JRE se usa como libreria  base, en este caso JavaSE9.

https://github.com/anncode1/JavaSEBasicoAvanzado/blob/32.AbstractClases/AmazonViewer/.classpath

Basta con reconfigurar el Build Path para utilizar el JRE que tengas disponible en tu equipo (probablemente JRE8). Esto se hace en el menu "Project/Properties"

[image: Project Properties]

y luego en la ventana hacer doble clic sobre JRE System Library y cambiar el JRE por alguno de los disponibles de la lista (JavaSE1.8 por ejemplo)

Ademas, el `makefile.jar` que se incluye esta usando una ruta absoluta del creador del codigo, que no existe en tu equipo. Debes hacer doble clic sobre esta entrada y buscar/seleccionar el archivo makefile.jar dentro de la carpeta del projecto (en carpeta `AmazonViewer/bin`).

Al guardar esta configuracion el codigo deberia ser compilable y ejecutable.

Comment: Ya lo pude resolver muchísimas gracias